# Move rename and zip files

Tags: windows, batch-file

My oracle server is in `windows 2008 64 bit`. I need to move listner.log files to

```
 E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs
```

from

```
E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\alert\
```

I need to rename that file as `currentdate.log` and my log directory and log name is

```
E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ClearListenerLog.log
```

I need to zip the file after i rename it and my 7-ZIP is installed in

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.EXE.
```

I will appreciate if some one can help me out to write all this in batch script as I am new to windows script.

Comment: Can you please re-read your question and see if the details are listed in the right order?  You're saying a log file is in `alert` folder, you want them renamed to `20140112.log` but then you say that the log is in a different folder `ClearListenerLog`.  I don't quite follow you.

Comment: The location of lister.log  is :\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\alert\

Comment: i want to move them by renaming and ziping to new location. The new location is E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs. The renaming of zipping file will be like listener_ddmmyyy.zip

Comment: ok.  Just one more question - how many logs are there?  You said `move them` but you only gave one filename.

Comment: Thank you foxdrive. The concept should be that it will move file one by one and zip file one by one.I infact moving oracle listener file from its default location to new location because it get bigger causing performance issues.If you just can kindly help me out to script for one log file that will suffice my need. I will take care rest of it. Thanks again

Comment: I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once.  You apparently duplicated this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738820/write-script-in-batch-to-rename-and-move-the-file-in-7zip/21742942#21742942

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
@echo off
set "source=E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\alert"
set "target=E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "datestamp=%DD%%MM%%YY%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
for %%a in ("%source%\*.log") do (
set /a c+=1
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.EXE" a "%target%\listener_%datestamp%_!c!.7z" "%%a"
if not errorlevel 1 del "%%a"
)
```

Comment: This should work -- it is similar to my solution in his duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738820/write-script-in-batch-to-rename-and-move-the-file-in-7zip/21742942#21742942.  Note that you do not need the for loop.  you can use %date% directly.

Comment: @beel Thanks.  The problem with using `%date%` is that it may or may not work on any given computer, because the format can be changed by the user, as well as changing in different regions.  Using WMIC or VBS or Powershell to get the date and time in a known format is a better solution when providing support for people that can be anywhere in the world too.

Comment: Thanks both Foxdrive and Beel spending valuable time to this. Happy valentines day both of you

Comment: If i want to move another file to same location from source location E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\el010\listener_scan1 and zip it seperately , how i can do it. I want to delete zip files older than 10 days  at then end from E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs.

Comment: The idea of Stack Overflow is to accept an answer that works for you - by clicking the grey tick next to it.  If you have further questions then open a new question.

Comment: E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog>clearlistenerlog1.bat

E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog>

Comment: You seemed to be happy with the script 6 days ago.  What has changed?