# Write script in batch to rename and move the file in 7zip

Tags: batch-file

My 7-zip is installed in

> C:\Program Files\7-Zip

and my source log file location is

> E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\trace\listener.log

There is only one log file in there. I want to zip it by renaming name like  current date **LISTNER_DDMMYY.ZIP** to new destination to

> E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs

I would appreciate if  someone can help me to write in batch script since I am new to this script. I appreciate your help.

Comment: My 7-zip is installed in

    C:\Program Files\7-Zip

and my source log file location is

    E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\trace\listener.log

There is only one log file in there. I want to zip it by renaming name like current date LISTNER_DDMMYY.ZIP to new destination to

    E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs

I would appreciate if someone can help me to write in batch script since I am new to this script. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a E:\DBA_CMDS\Maintenance_Tasks\ClearListenerLog\ArchivedListenerLogs\listen_%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~12,2%.zip E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\trace\listener.log
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 DEL E:\OracleGrid\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\enctcorl010\listener\trace\listener.log
```

This assumes that the 7-zip command line has been installed in the 7-zip directory you mention.  It is a separate download / install.
HTH.

Comment: you're welcome -- if it is helpful, pls upvote or mark answered.  same for the solution from @foxidrive on your other post if that one works better in your case.

Comment: My question has been answered. Thanks